# How to get a list of all conditional access policy groups a particular user is part of?

Tags: azure, powershell

Using the PowerShell MsolService Module, is it possible to get all of the conditional access policies attached to a particular user?

Is this possible with the MsolService module, cannot seem to find much online? Thanks again for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with the AzureAD module

```
$UserID = "email_address"
 
Try {
    #Connect to Azure AD
    Connect-AzureAD -Credential (Get-Credential) | Out-Null
 
    #Get the User
    $User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserID
 
    #Get User's Group Memberships
    $Memberships = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $User.ObjectId | Where-object { $_.ObjectType -eq "Group" }
 
    $Memberships = $Memberships.DisplayName
    For ($index=0; $index -lt $Memberships.Length; $index++) {
        Write-Host $Memberships[$index]
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "`tError:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?